# compatibility between React.JS and java

Tags: java, reactjs

I have a question that tapped me. can someone help?
Here is my question:
can **react** front end be used with **java**? 
If yes How is it possible? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Java is for the backend, react is for the front end. No reason they can't work together. You may want to read up on how the different technologies actually work.

Comment: I am asking how more than if it is possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use react front end and java as back end.
Let us assume you want to build simple school management application with following feature.
In home page we want to show simple three tab `student` `teacher` and `admin`.By clicking over each tab it should show a page containg that partucular user realted data(userName, picture, address).

We will be having simple Mysql database to store user information.

**Use React:**
To build this I will use express as framework to use React.In React I will be having component `HomePage` and `UserInfo`.
When we click any tab on home page we need to fetch data from database.
To call an external api I will use `redux` and save data in redux store.
Your frontend will be running on express(assume on localhost:3000)

**Use Java:**
As backend Let us assume we want some manipulation of data so we will use java(use jersey to make rest apis).In java we can make connection to database and fetch data.Using java we will make a post api taking `user type` which return user data in json format.This json will be stored in redux store.So in new page after clicking I will iterarte through this data and show in page.
Your backend in java will be running on tomcat(assume on localhost:8000)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, in fact java and react or any other front-end technologies should not have a problem communicating to each other. You may want to do some readings on Representational state transfer (REST).